# Range with variable column and lastrow not working

Tags: vba, excel, variables, range

I have a macro that finds the header and put the column in a variable, after that it creates a collection of data and removes the duplicated values, pasting the results in another fixed locations. I can't figure out the line to do the FOR EACH CELL. The original macro I've found contained "For each cell in .range("A1:A" & rlastcell) and it worked properly on column A. I need the column to be set to a variable, so it will take all the values from that column and remove the duplicates.

This is the code I have. Thank you in advance.

```
    Sub copyNoDuplicates()
Dim rLastCell As Range
Dim cell As Range, i As Long
Dim AccTeam As Collection
Dim lCol As Long
Dim rFind As Range

Set rFind = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet2").Rows("1:3").Find(What:="Accountable Team", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
lCol = rFind.Column

Set AccTeam = New Collection
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    'Find last used cell
    Set rLastCell = .Range("A65536").End(xlUp)
    'Parse every animal and put it in a collection
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each cell In .Cells(rLastCell, lCol)
        AccTeam.Add cell.Value, CStr(cell.Value)
    Next cell
    On Error GoTo 0
End With
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    For i = 1 To AccTeam.Count
        .Range("D" & i).Value = AccTeam(i)
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to Cyril's idea. When using Find also a good idea to check first that the search term is found to avoid your code erroring.

```
Sub copyNoDuplicates()

Dim rLastCell As Range
Dim cell As Range, i As Long
Dim AccTeam As Collection
Dim lCol As Long
Dim rFind As Range

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set rFind = .Rows("1:3").Find(What:="Accountable Team", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
        lCol = rFind.Column
        Set AccTeam = New Collection
        'Use the relevant column to find last cell
        Set rLastCell = .Cells(Rows.Count, lCol).End(xlUp)
        On Error Resume Next
        'Range from 1st row of column to last
        For Each cell In .Range(.Cells(1, lCol), rLastCell)
            AccTeam.Add cell.Value, CStr(cell.Value)
        Next cell
        On Error GoTo 0
        For i = 1 To AccTeam.Count
            .Range("D" & i).Value = AccTeam(i)
        Next i
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You will most likely need to switch to using Cells() structure to save time/effort.

```
Dim i As Range, j As Long, lr As Long
Set i = Range(Rows(1), Rows(3)).Find(What:="Accountable Team", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
j = i.Column
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, j).End(xlUp).Row
Range(Cells(2, j), Cells(lr, j)).Value = "" 'assumes header in row 1
```

The use of A1:A & rlastcell as the range would need to convert the found column with appropriate header back into a letter, given the found columns #, which in my opinion seems like a waste.

Comment: Thank you, but this line throws me Syntax error: j = application.columns(range(rows(1),rows(3)).find(What:="Accountable Team", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
For Each cell In .Range("A1:A" & rLastCell.Row).Columns(lCol)
```

thus using `lCol` as sort of offset column from column A